# The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dbcontext

I am trying to add a model instance filled with values to database but it is showing me error

> "The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed."

Here is my code

```
private async void timerHandlerFixerIO(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string html = string.Empty;
        string url = @"http://api.fixer.io/latest";

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip;

        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            html = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }

        Debug.WriteLine(html);
        FixerIO FixerIOInstance = new FixerIO();
        FixerIOInstance.rates = new rates();
        FixerIOInstance = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FixerIO>(html);
        db.FixerIOs.Add(FixerIOInstance);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();

    }
```

Error exception popup appear on executing this line

```
db.FixerIOs.Add(FixerIOInstance);
```

and my `DbContext` declaration outside the `timerHandlerFixerIO` method like

```
private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
```

Comment: Rather than adding a note about your writing style, why not just correct it to normal English?

Comment: where is `db` declared ?

Comment: Its Inside controller

Comment: `private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();`

Comment: Somewhere else disposes the db context before `timerHandlerFixerIO` gets executed.

Comment: I Would Love To Do That @DannyChen Can You Guide Me How To _**disposes the db context before timerHandlerFixerIO gets executed**_

Comment: @AliJamal I guess `timerHandlerFixerIO` is triggered by a timer or something, the db context is not available at that time. If my guess is correct, you shouldn't put the timer inside a controller.

Comment: Probably I Used Answer From @Mostafiz It Is Now Working Perfectly
Thank You

Comment: off topic: preferably, you should return a Task when marking a method as async, since you can't do that in this case you should at least wrap your code in a try-catch statement.

Comment: Salaamun Alekum @FredrikRedin I Tried But `void` Can Not Be Enveloped By `TASK<void>` Like This It Gives Me Error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `DbContext` again this way

```
using(var db = new ApplicationDbContext())
{
   db.FixerIOs.Add(FixerIOInstance);
   await db.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Comment: Yes It Worked Thank You Now Values Are Storing In Database At Every Iteration Of Timer Tick Thank You So Much I Would Not Have Figured This Out By My Self Thank You